# how to input date and time along with location in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the date, time and location into their respective fields with the click of one button...

Here is the code I am working with...

```
  <label>Latitude:</label> <input type="text" id="latitude1" name="Latitude1" value=""       readonly />
    <label>Longitude:</label> <input type="text" id="longitude1" name="Longitude1" value="" readonly />
     <label>Date / Time:</label> <input type="text" id="Time Check In"  size="50" class="field left" readonly/>
     <input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" onclick="getLocationConstant(1)"; onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();"/>
```

Comment: <label>Latitude:</label> <input type="text" id="latitude1" name="Latitude1" value="" readonly />
    <label>Longitude:</label> <input type="text" id="longitude1" name="Longitude1" value="" readonly />
     <label>Date / Time:</label> <input type="text" id="Time Check In"  size="50" class="field left" readonly/>
     <input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" onclick="getLocationConstant(1)"; onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();"/>

Comment: can you edit the q to put the code in? It is unreadable in the comments.

Comment: It just showed up on top... Do I need to post the javascript as well?

Comment: OK, so now it is readable, but I don't get what you are trying to do. 3 input fields - 1 each for latitude, longitude, datetime - and when you click the button, what should happen?

Comment: The lat and long input, but the date / time does not. For some reason it is not letting me paste the rest of the code.

Comment: All three are readonly, so clicking the button is supposed to fill them in for the user? Yeah, would need the js code as well. Should be able to paste it, but a fiddle works just as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/detbecker/k950f7a3/

Comment: @feeela accoring to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), no. That said, it works in Chrome 41.0.2228.2 (Official Build) canary.

Comment: Well, looks like @canon found it. Good show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

**1:** You've specified `onclick` twice. That won't work.

```
<input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" onclick="getLocationConstant(1)"; 
onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();"/>
```

**2:** `theDate` doesn't exist...

```
<input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" onclick="getLocationConstant(1)"; 
onclick="this.form.theDate.value = new Date();"/>
```

Your input id is `Time Check In`; use `document.getElementById()` to find it.

```
<input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" 
    onclick="getLocationConstant(1);document.getElementById('Time Check In').value = new Date();" />
```

Here's a demo:

```js
function getLocationConstant(){/* your location stuff */}
```

```html
<label>Latitude:</label>
<input type="text" id="latitude1" name="Latitude1" value="" readonly />
<label>Longitude:</label>
<input type="text" id="longitude1" name="Longitude1" value="" readonly />
<label>Date / Time:</label>
<input type="text" id="Time Check In" size="50" class="field left" readonly />
<input type="button" value="Get Location / Time" onclick="getLocationConstant(1);document.getElementById('Time Check In').value = new Date();"/>
```

Please note that the value specified for `id` should adhere to the following rules ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)):

> - must be at least one character long
> - must not contain any space characters

You have spaces in your `id`. Some browsers may allow that (Chrome does, for instance) but I wouldn't necessarily count on it.

Comment: @AvinashBabu from his html.

Comment: his html doesnt have theDate

Comment: @AvinashBabu scroll to the right in the code snippet in the question…

Comment: Good answer. @scott-m-becker Two hints: 1.) ID's in HTML are not allowed to contain spaces and 2.) you should move the logic like function calls into a separate function and just call that single function from the event handler instead of concatenating statements in the attribute.

Comment: @canon Oh, the W3C stated that space-thing even more explicit: „[An ID ] must not contain any space characters“. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Comment: Thank you all for the help and advice. I got it to work! Had to make some minor adjustments in the javascript.

Comment: @ScottM.Becker Don't forget to click the checkmark to accept the answer -provided that it worked for you.